# ¿Por qué la imagen del background se desplaza al salir el teclado IONIC 4?

Tags: ionic4, background

Tengo una imagen de fondo en el **login** de mi aplicación con los siguientes *html* y *css* pero al lanzarse el teclado para escribir el usuario y la contraseña se desplaza mi imagen de fondo y me gustaría saber cómo dejarla estática sin que el teclado la afecte .. si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia muchas gracias

```
<ion-content class="login-content" padding>
//contenido formulario(inputs username y password)
</ion-content>

.login-content{
        --background: url("../../assets/images/guardia2.jpg") no-repeat 
  center center/cover;
      }
```

Comment: Interesante pregunta, ¿Podrías poner una imagen de cual era exactamente como se veía y como se ve ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude Resolver de la Siguinte manera agregando la propiedad background-attachment a las clases de los elementos hijos espero que a alguien más le pueda servir esta solución

`.login-content{
            --background: url('../../assets/images/guardia2.jpg')0 0/cover no-repeat;
            --background-attachment: fixed!important;
            .main.inner-scroll.scroll-y.overscroll{
                --background-attachment: fixed!important;
            }
          }`

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre algo como esto y en mi caso con Ionic 4 cada vez que quiero agregar un fondo y que tengo que abrir el teclado funciona.

```
background-image: url("../../assets/images/guardia2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @ASASCED me fue de mucha ayuda te agradezco

Comment: @samuelsantos si te fue de utilidad marcala como respuesta correcta y dale un boto positivo para que cuando alguien mas de la comunidad pregunte por algo similar encuentre que aqui esta la respuesta.